# What is the default WSL distribution?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am specifically trying to understand which distribution is used pre "wsl --install" by the user.

Comment: How long does it take to find [this page on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#change-the-default-linux-distribution-installed)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this question came to my mind after reading that exact page. it tells you how to set/change the default Linux distro using wsl --install command. It DOES NOT inform what the default is. I repeat, I am specifically trying to understand which distribution is used pre "wsl --install" by the user.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh and to answer your question. It takes me less time to find official docs and more time to reply to comments like yours.